# Check boolean value from store and if false dispatch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

The idea is to fetch the profile data of a user a single time. My plan was to check the `isLoaded` boolean if the profile has previously been loaded or not. If it is false a getUser will be dispatched.

I'm only missing the checking `isLoaded` part and I'm failing miserably. As I can't find an other way than using a hook in an if statement.

What would be the proper way to achieve my goal?

```
export const getUser = (): ThunkAction<Promise<void>, {}, {}, AnyAction> => {
    if(!useSelector((state: State) => state.userProfile.isLoaded)) {
        return async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>): Promise<void> => {
            return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
                dispatch(isFetching(true));
                console.log("FETCHING PROFILE IN PROGRESS");
                setTimeout(() => {
                    let user = <User>{};
                    axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL + "/users/" + process.env.REACT_APP_USER_ID)
                        .then(response => {
                            user = response.data.data;
                            console.log("USER:", user);
                            dispatch(isLoaded(true));
                            dispatch(set(user));
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        dispatch(isFetching(false));
                        console.log("LOADED PROFILE");
                        resolve()
                    }, 1000)
                }, 3000)
            })
        }
    } else {
        return async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>): Promise<void> => {
            return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
                resolve();
            })
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you should manage the actions exactly like that.

In the store the user should be undefined at the start.

```
const state: UserState = {
  user: undefined,
  isFetching: false,
  lastTimeFetched: undefined,
  invalidated: true
}
```

Then You should check always if the user has a value in the store.

When you load the app, or the component, this will be undefined and you will make a call to the rest endpoint.

During the call to the endpoint, isFetching will be true.

After that, you should set user to the user that you got , lastTimeFetched to the time when you fetched the user, and invalidated to false.

Why the time and invalidated? Can be usefull, if you want to reload the user information after a certain time.

I think, you should check if the user field has a value, only the first time when you load a Functional Component that use that value.

Comment: I planned to do exactly what you are suggesting. I'm failing at the part to check the value from the store. I can't make this store call: `!useSelector((state: State) => state.userProfile.isLoaded)`

Comment: Why you can't just check that on useEffect / componentDidMount function? I think is the best place where it should be done.